# Unity Detect Compute shader completion

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

Since I haven't found much info elsewhere about compute shaders I'll ask here.

How can I detect/see if a compute shader has finished it's work? 
Or is it assumed that the main thread waits for the shader to complete?

If that's the case, is there a way of not having the main thread wait for the shader and just have a flag in the shader instead?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this question was asked, but I'll add an answer for anyone looking in the future!

`ComputeShader.Dispatch` is synchronous, and will block the CPU until the compute shader has finished running. This is typically quite fast unless your compute shader is doing a significant amount of work, in which case you may need to use a different interface.

Since this question was asked, Unity has implemented both "Async Compute" support via the `CommandBuffer` interface, as well as a `GraphicsFence` interface for GPU synchronization.

- `Graphics.ExecuteCommandBufferAsync` allows asynchronous execution of `CommandBuffers` on platforms which support it, falling back to synchronous execution if needed.
- `GraphicsFence` provides an interface to create named "fences" on the GPU. These are essentially signals that are triggered when execution of a GPU queue has progressed past the point where they are added. Typically, you would use fences to specify dependencies between different GPU compute stages, where one queue would create a fence and another would wait on it - for example, one async compute queue may depend on the results of an earlier queue, and could wait on a fence to ensure that the required data is ready before the dependent queue is executed.

A `GraphicsFence` can be queried on the CPU as well using `GraphicsFence.passed`. This is a fairly primitive interface, but it does the job here. Using both of these in conjunction, the desired behavior could be achieved like this.

```cs
class MyAsyncComputeTest: MonoBehaviour 
{
   private GraphicsFence graphicsFence;
   private CommandBuffer commandBuffer;
   private ComputeShader computeShader;
   
   private void Start()
   {
        // Create a new CommandBuffer.
        // The CommandBuffer acts as a queue of commands to run on the GPU.
        commandBuffer = new CommandBuffer();

        // Configure the CommandBuffer to run asynchronously.
        commandBuffer.SetExecutionFlags(CommandBufferExecutionFlags.AsyncCompute);

        // Enqueue a command to dispatch the compute shader.
        commandBuffer.DispatchCompute(computeShader, 0, 1, 1, 1);

        // Create a graphics fence. CommandBuffers are executed in order,
        // so this fence will be passed when the DispatchCompute has finished.
        graphicsFence = commandBuffer.CreateGraphicsFence(GraphicsFenceType.CPUSynchronization, SynchronisationStageFlags.ComputeProcessing);

        // Finally, execute the CommandBuffer asynchronously.
        Graphics.ExecuteCommandBufferAsync(commandBuffer, ComputeQueueType.Default);
   }

   private void Update()
   {
        // The CommandBuffer created in `Start` is running asynchronously.
        // Check if the GraphicsFence created within it has passed.
        if (graphicsFence.passed)
        {
            // The graphics fence has passed and the compute shader has finished running.
            commandBuffer.Dispose();
        }
   }
}
```